# natürlich klingen

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

Ich möchte wissen, ob der folgende Satz natürlich klingt:

> Es ist richtig, wenn man wollen, zu ausdrücken, dass etwas eine Kennline des Stein haben.
>
> It is right, when one wants to express that something has the characteristic of a stone.

Answer (score 3):

Leider gar nicht. Die Fehler sind:

1. *wollen*: muss korrekt konjugiert werden → *man will*
2. *zu ausdrücken*: bei zusammengesetzten Verben, wandert das *zu* in Infinitivsätzen in die Mitte: → *auszudrücken*
3. *auszudrücken* ist kein Nebensatz, sondern gehört zu *wollen* → *wenn man ausdrücken will*, dabei fällt das *zu* weg
4. *Kennlinie* ist keine Übersetzung von *characteristic*. Verwende *Charakteristik*
5. *Stein* muss dekliniert werden (Genitiv) → *des Steins*
6. Im Englischen wird der unbestimmte Artikel *a* verwendet, der mit dem unbestimmten Artikel *ein* übersetzt wird (*der/des* ist bestimmt) → *eines Steins*
7. *haben* muss konjugiert werden → *hat*

Korrekt müsste es also heißen:

> Es ist richtig, wenn man ausdrücken will, dass etwas die Charakteristik eines Steins hat.

Ohne Kontext ergibt das zwar keinen Sinn, aber es ist zumindest grammatikalisch korrekt.

Comment: Vielen Dank!, jetzt kann ich meine Fehler sehen.

Comment: Ich würde anstatt *Charakteristik* lieber *Merkmale* verwenden.